# Function between $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb{C}[x])$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb{R}[x])$

Tags: functions, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I was asked to describe $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb{C}[x])$ and $\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb{R}[x])$. After describing them, I want to find the natural function $\phi:\operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb{C}[x])\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(\Bbb{R}[x])$ corresponding to the embedding $\psi:\Bbb{R}[x]\rightarrow\Bbb{C}[x]$. Now to my understanding, the embedding is simply $\psi(f(x))=f(x)$. So my attempt at describing this natural function is:

$\phi(\langle f\rangle)=
\begin{cases} 
      \langle 0\rangle & f=0\\
      \langle f\rangle & f\in\Bbb{R}[x] \\
      \langle f\bar f\rangle & f\in\Bbb{C}[x]\setminus\Bbb{R}[x] 
   \end{cases}
\
$

This feels the most natural to me, but am I missing something? There's no claim that this function has to be injective/surjective, but I can't see how it corresponds to the embedding. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the map $\phi$ suppose to go the other direction? That is $\mbox{Spec}(\mathbb C[x])\rightarrow\mbox{Spec}(\mathbb R[x])$?

Comment: @Alessandro Yes I'll edit it now

Comment: Note that $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$. So, your function $\varphi$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @cos_dm_math21 How come? $\psi$ is defined from $\Bbb{R}[x]$ to $\Bbb{C}[x]$ regardless of irreducibility.

Comment: A hint to maybe give a bit more understanding: what do members of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ look like, and how does that differ from what members of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[x])$ look like?

Comment: Hint: $\phi'=\mbox{Spec}(\phi):\mbox{Spec}(A)\rightarrow\mbox{Spec}(B)$ corresponding to a map $\phi:B\rightarrow A$ is defined as $\phi'(I)=\phi^{-1}(I)$ (that is, $\phi'$ maps an ideal $I\in\mbox{Spec}(A)$ to the inverse image $\phi^{-1}(I)$)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Both are the union of the zero ideal with the ideals that are generated by irreducible polynomials

Comment: And what are the differences between irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]$, and how do they correspond to each other?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Every irreducible polynomial over the complex field is just a polynomial of degree 1, and every irreducible polynomial over the real field is either of degree 1 or is the product of two irreducible polynomials over the complex field.

Comment: And that's your correspondence — in going from $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ via the inclusion, some polynomials 'lose' irreducibility and so the ideals generated by those polynomials are no longer prime. Instead, there are two polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ whose prime ideals contain the one from $\mathbb{R}[x]$; your mapping takes both of those ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ to the corresponding one in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki So basically how I defined it doesn't hold?

Comment: @GBA No, what you defined looks correct to me — I was trying to explain how it _does_ correspond to the inclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a field $K$, every element in $I\in \operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ is either the ideal $(0)$ or corresponds to a unique monic irreducible polynomial $p$ such that $(p)=I$.

The map $\phi':\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb C[x])\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb R[x])$ corresponding to the embedding $j:\mathbb R[x]\hookrightarrow\mathbb C[x]$ sends the ideal $(0)$ to $(0)$, while an ideal $(p)$ (for $p$ a monic irreducible polynomial) is sent to the ideal $$\{f\in\mathbb R[x]|f=j(f)\in(p)\}=\{f\in\mathbb R[x]|f=qp,\mbox{ for some }q\in\mathbb C[x]\}
$$
As said in the comments, a monic irreducible polynomial $p\in\mathbb C[x]$ is a 1 degree polynomial $p=x-\theta$, for some $\theta\in\mathbb C$, so you just need to describe the ideal $\phi'(x-\theta)=\{f\in\mathbb R[x]|f\in (x-\theta)\}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[X]) = \{(0)\} \cup \{(aX+b) \ \big| \ a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a\neq 0 \} \cup \{(aX^2+bX+c) \ \big| \ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a\neq 0, \ b^2-4ac<0 \}$$
while
$$\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X]) = \{(0)\} \cup \{(aX+b)  \ \big| \ a,b \in \mathbb{C}, a\neq 0 \} $$